# How to convert Softsub Video file to Hardsub Video file?

Tags: video, convert, mkv

How to convert Soft-sub Video file to Hard-sub Video file ?

I have many mkv video files but I can't watch this videos because the subtitles don’t appear so I want to convert this files to Hard-sub without changing subtitles fonts or anything in this videos.

is there any way to do it?

Comment: Just followed and verified correctness of suggestions of following link:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930396